# menu_done cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_done:
    myResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

Here is an error which i'm facing. In "menu_done" Please help me to resolve         this  error rom code.

Comment: are you sure you have menu_done as an id in xml

Comment: Not an answer, a request: please **indent your code**!

Comment: It is already done with it

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Make sure you are inflating the right res\menu xml file:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_file_name, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

2. Make sure you have the specific menu item in your menu xml file:

   ```
   <menu>
       <item android:id="@+id/menu_done"
             android:title="@string/menu_done" />
   </menu>
   ```

Comment: there is no XMl in name of menu item or menu xml file